# Installing civicrm-4.7.19-l10n suggestions

Tags: wordpress, 4.7, i18n

1. Installation instructions for civicrm-4.7.19-l10n.tar should be included as a step in **Upgrading CiviCRM for WordPress/Joomla/Drupal**. The **Internationalisation (i18n)** section accessible from **Upgrade ...** does not give download instructions either.
2. A **zip version** would be nice for WordPress at least. My client's IP does not have the ability to untar files. I have to untar unzip and rezip and add .zip each time before I download it.
3. It is **unclear** whether the zip files go into *civicrm or civicrm\civicrm*. As I download both files into the plugin directory for extraction, I assume it is civicrm. If it should be civicm\civicrm, then add the extra directory into the zip/tar file. Selectrum will only extract to the current directory. Yes, I wish I had SSH.

Thank you

Comment: Since Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, there's no good format for non-questions here.  You may want to take this to chat (https://chat.civicrm.org) or the forums (https://forum.civicrm.org/)

Comment: I have no access to chat,civicrm.org and forum.civicrm.org is being phased out in favour of here. I was hoping that the development team monitors this site for problems as well as suggestions. I wouldn't mind assisting the team by updating the Wiki as I suggested.

Comment: Updating the wiki would be great, thanks!  Could you say more about having no access to chat.civicrm.org?  If there's some barrier to using it, I want to make sure the infrastructure team knows about it.

Comment: Added the instructions to the upgrade wiki.